# Identify tree with large pink flowers

Tags: identification, trees, flowers

Blooming in early spring in the US Northwest.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not exactly a tree, more of a large shrub - it is a *Camellia*, possibly *Camellia williamsii* of some variety, not sure which, though I've come across this one myself in a garden, never was able to pin down precisely which variety it was other than it probably being what's known as a 'rose double' type. The pointed petals and neat shape of the flowers are not that common in camellia - some information and varieties shown here https://gardenerspath.com/plants/ornamentals/best-camellia-varieties/

Comment: It is a Japonica camellia . Vert similar to "Debutant" , an old hardy ,common variety ( it possibly is Debutant)..

Comment: It is not 'debutant' - that has a lot more petals, see link in the answer for image.

Comment: Correct, The bush looks so vigorous like Debutant , I let it influence me.